# Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 Can't login to some secure website logins

Tags: 14.04, login, security, 14.10

I can generally google to find solutions to problems I have with Ubuntu, but this one has me stumped.

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 for several months, on this computer. I use Chrome as my primary browser, and Firefox as a backup. Several weeks ago, I noticed that I couldn't log in to my bank's website anymore. I can enter my login information as I always have, but when I click on their "LOGIN" button, I get no response. I found a similar problem on another secure website I tried to login to recently. The problem is on both Chrome and Firefox, and on two separate laptops that I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 on. Today, I updated my main laptop to 14.10, but I am still having the same problem. I also updated my java today to this:

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Same problem. This is the website on which the "LOGIN" button won't work for me: https://www.unitusccu.com/

Their website looked exactly the same a month ago as it does now, and I've had no problems in the past. I've also made no major changes to my system in the last month, until today (updating to 14.10 and Java 8).

Help?

Comment: I just tried logging in as user 'test' and get the error message "*We're sorry. The User ID, Account Number or Password was incorrect. Please try again. (6300, -6302)"*. Also, I can see the site uses Java**Script** (not Java) to display the login box. Do you have JavaScript disabled, and do you get an error message which may help troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if Java has any relation to your login problem, unless it was heavily used by the site. The browsers are culprits and, of course, a website. I can guess the following possibilities:
 * new browsers had dropped some SSL protocols that the website is using (there was big shock recently, so-called POODLE SSL attack);
 * or maybe their web site has changed, this happens sometimes;
 * or, sad to tell, there might be banking trojan at your machine (low probability but not zero) -- just try to login there from other machine;
 * or, they say about third-party partner sites, after login your browser might attempt to redirect to some site that stopper working.
It is almost impossible to diagnose something that cannot be reproduced (how can I login to see).

Anyway I suggest contacting bank support personnel, they get paid to help customers.

A side note: one can install old Java 7 currently without problem.